# UIImage from a URL that change by date

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nsurl

my question is simple, i want to load a UIImage from an URL, but this URL change programmatically by date.

Example Today the url is `http://www.abc.com/2011-10-13/alfa.jpg`

tomorrow is `http://www.abc.com/2011-10-14/alfa.jpg`

the only thing that change is the date part, how can i figure my app load that "alfa.jpg" at current date everytime i start it?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use NSDate class to get current date and pass it as an argument...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `[NSDate date]` which returns the current date and time according to the device time (assuming your device time doesn't differ from the actual by more than a day). Then you should format the date according to your url. Something like-

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString* dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[formatter release];
```

Comment: You are just off as `mm` will extract the minutes and not the month.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to generate the part of the string that varies with time.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString * datePart = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString * theURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/%@/alfa.jpg", datePart];
```

You will have to maintain a mechanism to check whether if the image for the day has been downloaded to avoid downloading it again.

Comment: You are leaking dateFormatter. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Create a template of the url you are using `nstring` and a DateFormatter object...

```
NSDateFormatter *df   = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *todayStr    = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *todayUrl    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/%@/alfa.jpg", todayStr];
```

`todayUrl` has the url for today!

Answer (score -1):

Its an easy task just format your URL string using current date like,

```
NSString *URLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/%@/alfa.jpg", currentDate];
```

Then use this string for URL request.